# Angular - render component without rendering everything else in app.component.ts

Tags: angular

I have a simple `Users` component. This is specified in my `app.routing.module.ts` file with a `/Users` route.

As convention, I also have an `app.component.html` which looks something like this:

```
<header>
...
</header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer>
...
</footer>
```

When navigating to `/Users` it activates the `UserComponent` and inserts it into the router-outlet as per Angular conventions.

I also have a requirement to host this component in a 3rd party tool as a custom embedded page. As such, I wouldn't want to render the header and footer.

Is there any way in Angular to render just the activated component but not render everything else in the root component when activating a route?

I've tried passing in a data object `renderRoot` into my router which is a boolean and conditionally renders the header and footer if true but this doesn't work as the root component doesn't receive the `data` object, only the child (user) component does.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated here.

**Update:**

Managed to get it working with the following code in my `app.component.ts`:

```
    this.activatedRoute.url.subscribe((event) => {
      if (this.location.path().toLowerCase().includes('thirdparty')) {

        this.isThirdParty = true;
      } else {
        this.isThirdParty = false;
      }
    });
```

I then use the `isThirdParty` flag to show/hide the sidebar and footer accordingly. I've designed all my third party components to ensure that they will always have this segment in their activation url.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you just use the `UserComponent` inside the 3rd-party tool? Considering that you're going to hide everything else inside the parent component, probably this would be the best solution.

Anyway, to achieve your goal, you can use `ActiveRoute` inside `app.component.ts` to detect the current route and act accordingly.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

// Just simulating that we're in a 3rd-party context.
// Of course you'll need to implement your own logic to detect this case
is3rdParty: boolean = true;
shouldHide: boolean = false;


@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.url.subscribe((event) => {
      if (this.is3rdParty && event[0].path === '/Users') {
        this.shouldHide = true;
      } else {
        this.shouldHide = false;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Then, in your template:

```html
<header *ngIf="!shouldHide">
...
</header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer *ngIf="!shouldHide">
...
</footer>
```

If i understood your needs correctly, with this code you can use the same component both in your main application and in every 3rd-party tools.

When `AppComponent` detect a route-change, it will check if the route is `/Users`. If so, and also if `is3rdParty` variable is set to `true` (maybe using a `@Input` or another internal logic), `shouldHide` will become `true` and your template will hide unnecessary parts.

### UPDATE

You can use this code to check if your app is running inside an `iframe`:

```js
function inIFrame () {
    try {
        return window.self !== window.top;
    } catch (e) {
        // fallback in case of errors
        return true;
    }
}

// ...
// Then, where you need it
// ...
// this.shouldHide = this.inIFrame;
```

Be careful: use of `window` object directly in your components is discouraged due to possible conflics (ex. `window` object is only available inside browsers. If you run your app in different ways, your code will not work correctly).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The second response makes sense. When you say "why don't you just use the UserComponent inside the 3rd-party tool?" are you able to elaborate on this? For some context, the 3rd party tool requires components embedded in iframes and traditionally I've seen the components specified as url's. This is why I thought of the idea to expose a route for the component, and specify that route in the iframe, but I might be missing a trick here.

Comment: @user483934 i thought your component would be integrated in other projects, i didn't understand that you were talking about providing the original project inside an Iframe. I've updated my answer explaining how is possible to "detect" if you're running inside an iframe

Comment: The IFrame suggestion looks good, thanks. I've been curious and tried implementing the first suggestion but looks like I can't subscribe on the `url` and without subscribe, the `url` just returns `/` (root) instead of the child component url

Comment: Can you share your code? I've just tested `ActivatedRoute` on a test project and works well. Which version of Angular are you using?

Comment: Sorry - PICNIC error, was using Router instead of ActivatedRoute. Will give this a shot now, thank you

Comment: So looks like with your exact code in the root component, the event path is null. The json I get is:
`{
    "path": "",
    "parameters": {}
}`. What version of Angular are you using and is your code called in the root component?

Comment: Just an update - I didn't get this working using the `ActivatedRoute` but I managed to get it working similarly using the LocationModule. I'll add my code in the answer for others.